# Ensure identical values across subset of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table that keeps track of users that are assigned to slots in a bucket:

```
BUCKET_ID  SLOT_ID  USERNAME
0          0        bob
0          1        bob
0          2        bob
1          0        suzy
1          1        suzy
2          0        chris
3          0        bob
```

A user can occupy multiple slots. In fact, a user can occupy multiple buckets. But I need to enforce that a bucket can only have one user. That is, Bob and Suzy cannot occupy slots 0 and 1 in the same bucket.

Is there a way to enforce this logic in the database? That is, make an offending insert transaction fail.

The only way I know for a transaction to fail is if it violates a unique index. So I'm working on a trigger that updates some secondary table, one that exists solely to contain a unique index.

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute select query before insert to validate insert and then conditionally insert record?
like

```
  select username from table where bucket_id = 0 and username <> 'suzy'
```

If above query return no record then insert is valid else another user already owns a bucket and insert is invalid

Comment: Yes, this would rely on my application to enforce the uniqueness. But I'd like for it to be "database impossible" for a conflict to exist. This way, as the application scales up to support higher concurrency, my data is protected.